# Update n number of records using JPA with Optimistic locking

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc, ejb-3.0

I have a table with a column called "count" and I want to run a cron job that will trigger a statement that performs a SQL like this:

```
update summaryTable set count=4;
```

Note that there might be concurrent threads reading & changing the value for "count" when this cron job is triggered. The table has a version column to support Optimistic Locking.

What's an efficient way to update the count in JPA ?

Comment: What is the optimistic locking behavior you're looking for?  You want your job to fail if someone else changes a row?  You want your job to cause other people's transactions to fail if you change the row while they're working?  Or you want your job to not cause optimistic locking errors?


One assumes it's not the first, since a job that sets rows to an arbitrary value probably doesn't prove much by respecting someone else's optimistic lock.

Comment: Readers really need feedback on the above comment to answer this question. Could you also mention your JPA provider (there might be provider specific solutions for this)?

Comment: I want some other mutating operations to fail since my job is a batch update. I am using eclipselink.

Answer (score 0):

Using JPA you can also perform updates using JPQL if you have an entity for that table. You can do this with the [query.executeUpdate()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) function.

Something like: UPDATE SummaryTableEntity ent SET ent.count = 4 .

Since this is also tagged as EJB3 if your cron schedule is simple enough you could set up an EJB Timer which runs a method that performs the update. That way you are managing all your timed tasks in container and do not have to worry about external concurrency.